# StartRecognizeCustomFormsFromUri returns "Parameter 'Source' is not a valid Uri." for file URI

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

Using Azure.AI.FormRecognizer 1.0.0-preview.2 and trying to upload a file and then run forms recognition on it. Code is

```
var fileName = Path.Combine(@"c:\temp\", sourceFile.FileName);
var fileUri = new Uri(fileName);
sourceFile.SaveAs(fileName);

var forms = await recogClient.StartRecognizeCustomFormsFromUri(modelId, fileUri).WaitForCompletionAsync();
```

The file URI becomes, for example, `file:///c:/temp/DC002.pdf` which I believe is a valid URI. However, when running `StartRecognizeCustomFormsFromUri`, I get the error:

```
Service request failed. Status: 400 (Bad Request) Content: {"error":{"code":"1003","message":"Parameter 'Source' is not a valid Uri."}} Headers: Transfer-Encoding: chunked x-envoy-upstream-service-time: REDACTED apim-request-id: REDACTED Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED x-content-type-options: REDACTED Date: Wed, 27 May 2020 12:30:01 GMT Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileUri` needs to be a public accessible URL, you can not point to your local filesystem. If you would like to send a local file, you should send the file as a file stream.

The Uri is a great way to speed up the processing when your files are already on a blob storage, or any other public accessible cloud storage, saving time of not streaming the file to the Form Recognizer service.

- [Recognize forms from
  File](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer_1.0.0-preview.2/sdk/formrecognizer/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer/tests/samples/Sample3_RecognizeCustomFormsFromFile.cs)
- [Recognize forms from Uri](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer_1.0.0-preview.2/sdk/formrecognizer/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer/tests/samples/Sample3_RecognizeCustomFormsFromUri.cs)

Comment: Any Idea Recognize forms from File has a Python implimentation?

Comment: @JIJOJOSEPH please have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ai-formrecognizer-readme-pre?view=azure-python.

Comment: Thanks for the links anyway , however i used the REST API only ,and in particular to Upload a file(png) to form recognizer and get the analysis i set the header content-type to image/png  and added the binary data in the body. To add file content as binary i used BytesIO package . It worked.